# show alert at on a date given by user?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

i am making a application in which user enter a date when he want to see an alert,
i have taken the date and stores in database,and sorted date,what is the best way how we schedule them and how?
please send me Code as well
I am knew in Blackberry 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look to class **java.util.Timer**
method schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)